# Select column data with condition and move it to new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe looked like below.

```
T$QOOR
   3
  14
  12
  -6
 -19
   9
```

I want to move the positive and negative one into new columns.

```
sls_item['SALES'] = sls_item['T$QOOR'].apply(lambda x: x if x >= 0 else 0)
sls_item['RETURN'] = sls_item['T$QOOR'].apply(lambda x: x*-1 if x < 0 else 0)
```

The result will be as below.

```
T$QOOR    SALES    RETURN    
   3        3         0
  14       14         0
  12       12         0
  -6        0        -6
 -19        0       -19
   9        9         0
```

Any better and cleaner way to do so other than using `apply`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with [`clip_lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.clip_lower.html) and
[`clip_upper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.clip_upper.html), also [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html) for multiple by `-1` is added:

```
sls_item['SALES'] = sls_item['T$QOOR'].clip_lower(0)
sls_item['RETURN'] = sls_item['T$QOOR'].clip_upper(0).mul(-1)
print (sls_item)
   T$QOOR  SALES  RETURN
0       3      3       0
1      14     14       0
2      12     12       0
3      -6      0       6
4     -19      0      19
5       9      9       0
```

Use [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
sls_item['SALES'] = sls_item['T$QOOR'].where(lambda x: x >= 0, 0)
sls_item['RETURN'] = sls_item['T$QOOR'].where(lambda x: x < 0, 0) * -1
print (sls_item)
   T$QOOR  SALES  RETURN
0       3      3       0
1      14     14       0
2      12     12       0
3      -6      0       6
4     -19      0      19
5       9      9       0
```

---

```
mask = sls_item['T$QOOR'] >=0
sls_item['SALES'] = np.where(mask, sls_item['T$QOOR'], 0)
sls_item['RETURN'] = np.where(~mask, sls_item['T$QOOR'] * -1, 0)
print (sls_item)
   T$QOOR  SALES  RETURN
0       3      3       0
1      14     14       0
2      12     12       0
3      -6      0       6
4     -19      0      19
5       9      9       0
```

Comment: Take note that the negative value become positive in the new column

Answer (score 0):

`assgin` + `where`

```
df.assign(po=df.where(df['T$QOOR']>0,0),ne=df.where(df['T$QOOR']<0,0))
Out[1355]: 
   T$QOOR  ne  po
0       3   0   3
1      14   0  14
2      12   0  12
3      -6  -6   0
4     -19 -19   0
5       9   0   9
```